# How can I make a node template that works on any url I specify?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

At the moment I can make a template for a specific node based on the node id.
However I want to make the same template work off of the url or title of the node so I can use it on multiple sites for the same node which doesn't have the same node id on each of the sites.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best to add a template suggestion rule to [hook_preprocess_node](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7), to control which templates are looked for.

e.g, in template.php

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type == 'article') {
    // Regex replace anything not alphanumeric with underscore _ in node title
    $title = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '_', drupal_strtolower($variables['node']->title));
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'. $title; // Use title in template suggestion
  }

}
```

Then you could use a template like

```
node--my-node-title.tpl.php
```

Comment: This worked once I wrapped the node title with a string replace to sub - for _ but now I don't have any form vars coming through. I can get the form vars from $content['webform']['#form'] but it won't post.

Comment: OK, I'll update with a str_replace for that. What do you mean by form vars?

Comment: Webform is a different issue from node tpl question

Comment: The default webform template has "print drupal_render($form['submitted']);" and "print drupal_render_children($form);" to build the form in the template. These no longer work in the new template though?

Comment: Ah ok, can I adapt this approach for a webform? It appears that if I grab the form from the $content var and render it that there is no <form> it's just inputs in divs.

Comment: I ended up adding form alter and a theme hook to get my template working and form is processing now. Thanks for your help.